# Extracting the code from Keras

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, code

Suppose I write a program in Keras for MNIST data set. I used TensorFlow as my backend in Keras. Is it possible in any way that I can extract the backend code used for TensorFlow that has been used by Keras. if yes, please provide an example.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to compile code written for the Keras API to code only using the Tensorflow API, there is no ready-to-use solution for that. And I cannot see any good reason why someone would want to do that in the first place...

You can simply look at the [Keras backend source code for Tensorflow](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py) and rewrite your entire implementation. But once again I don't see any valid reason that would make this worth it.

Comment: It *might* be worthwhile for deployment. It removes Keras as a dependency on production systems for instance. You would use Keras as a quick way to build and prototype different networks, then discard it for pure TensorFlow version once you had found your ideal network. However, I agree in that I don't think there's much to gain in terms of performance or deployment effort between Keras+TensorFlow vs just TensorFlow (although in older versions there was, Keras did not use TensorFlow efficiently). It is not a huge effort to build a network natively in TensorFlow anyway.